# Do Linear Programming Solutions always occur as an interval?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Suppose the LP is : $\min f$ subject to a set of constraints where $f : \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$. Why is it that $x^{*}$ is always an interval instead of a union of disjoint sets?

Answer (score 2):

Solutions of linear programs are always convex, meaning that if $x$ and $y$ are solutions, $\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y$ is a solution as well for any $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

This comes from linearity of $f$: If $f(x)=f(y)$, For any $\lambda$ we have $f(x)=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y) = f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)$. Note that this really works for any $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. However, we might lose constraints if we leave the range $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

The only convex subsets of $\mathbb R$ are intervals, so the solution space is always an interval.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't think of this. Thank you @LurchiDerLurch.

Comment: And why is $\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)=f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)$?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri $\lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y) = \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(x) = f(x)$. This is equal to $f(\lambda x+(1−\lambda)y)$ since the min. cost is same at both $x$ and $\lambda x+(1−\lambda)y$ (as they both are solutions to the LP). Does that work?

Comment: @dictatemetokcus No, it follows from the linearity of $f$ that $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$. Thus if $f(x)=f(y)$, we will get $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)=f(x)\forall\lambda\in[0,1]$, meaning that the entire line joining $x,y$ has the optimum value.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that I didn’t frame this in an optimal way. I'm on the phone right now, I'll make sure to improve the answer once I‘m on a proper device.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri How do you fix this then?